# find the next non blank cell in excel and apply formula between the previous and next non blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hey Guys I have data from year 2009 to 2015, then 2016 to 2020 is blank, followed by a value in 2021 and then again blank cells till 2025. Here is what I want my formula to do:

1. In case the value is available, pick that value(very easy and don't need any help on this)
2. In case the value is not available, identify the next non blank cell (x2) and use it to create a formula something like:
   (x2-x1)/(no .of years) where no. of years is the difference in years of x2 and x1 (in first case it will be 2021-2015).
3. This will become the formula for 2016 and then repeat the same activity for 2017, and now the no. of years calculated will be between 2016 and 2021.

Any help on computations of this will be appreciated. Non vba solutions are requested for this.

Thanks

Comment: @abagshaw so what I have done so far is managed to identify a set of formula to get me the value of the next non-blank cell. I just need to identify how to use it to interpolate values. Since I am not able to send you any screenshots, I will write the formula down. O25 to O41 has years (2009 to 2025), P25 to P41 has values (blanks from P32 to P35). In Q25 I have following array formula written:

Comment: ={IF(P25<>"",INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($P$25:$P$41,MATCH(P25,$P$25:$P$41,0),1)),TRUE),INDIRECT("R"&ROW(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(P25:P41,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(P25:P41),0))),TRUE))&"C"&COLUMN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(P25:P41,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(P25:P41),0))),TRUE)),FALSE))}

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is interpolate between data for the known years.  Because you don't provide any data, I made up some in order to illustrate one approach.
[image]

The trend is based on an equation in cell B3, =5*SIN(B2/4), which is dragged down and plotted in blue in the chart. Similarly, the interpolation is based on an equation in D9, =4+(D$14-D8)/(ROW(D$14)-ROW(D8)), which is dragged down and plotted in red. The interpolation here is based on what you provided, but of course, the equation is just made up in order to somewhat approach the (made up) trend. Perhaps you can modify these concepts to fit with your situation and ask again if you still need help.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello Tony, thanks for your help. You have got the problem statement bang on. The only trouble with me is that I need to do this dynamically. There is a possibility that today data is available for 2021, while next time data is uploaded the same might not be true. Now the data is available for 2025 and hence I cannot fix the value of cell D14.

Comment: What I actually need to do is decide where the blanks are, fill them with the formula that you have shown above and then do the same for other blank cells. Hope this clarifies the problem statement more.

Comment: Yes, your problem statement is getting clearer.  The more "dynamic" the problem is the more VBA would be best, and easier to work with in the long run.  You could get a lot of good help here, not to mention learning a lot about a powerful approach.  I suggest you mark this one as answered, and move in that direction. Make up some sample data; hopefully, my example has encouraged you to do that.